# How long is the Google API key Valid?

Tags: oauth, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm am fetching playlist's details using [Youtube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) using API key.

I can't find any information about API KEY validity period.  I want to make sure I regenerate a new API key for my application before it expires.

Comment: Is it the API key itself, or the access token, that you need to renew?

Comment: when the public api key expires .only api key alone

Answer (score 6):

The public API key found at the bottom of the [Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com) APIs & auths -> credentials screen does not expire.  This is a key used for accessing public APIs like [Playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), it will remain valid for as long as you do not delete the key or delete the project associated with the key.   Its main purpose is for Google to keep track of who is using there APIs and to limit the number of requests you may make to prevent spamming the servers.  ([Quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota))

[image]

Access tokens are used for Open Authentication access and do expire.  Open Authentication (oauth2) is used for accessing non public data, data owned by a user. They are created  pragmatically by requesting them from the authentication server using a refresh token and a client id /client secrete.  I don't think this is what you are asking about, but I thought I would add it for reference.

Comment: welcome to stack that was a very good question.  Don't for get to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @jinsnow access tokens are used to access private user data and expired after an hour they are not related to public API keys please don't post unrelated comment on anwser this may confuse people unfamiliar to the inner workings of Oauth2