# Google places API key not works

Tags: android

Why Places Api do not work when creating a new project and a new key, but work with the old key from 2016? I have no bank cards and will not have any!

Did on different projects! Api included same!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is very less information in your question. Did you follow the Developers guide on how to set it up for your Android Project? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start

Comment: Added a question! Key from 2016 with the same api works great!

Comment: Should Google Places Api work without linking a bank card on android applications?

Answer (score 3):

Did you enable billing?

According to the documentation,

> To use the Places SDK for Android, you must include an API key with all API requests, and you must enable billing on each of your projects.

For details refer here [Places SDK for Android Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing)

Comment: Thanks you. Please tell me, you can't turn on billing without a bank card? I don't have one! My old keys from 2016 are working fine, will they be locked in the future?

Comment: If you are asking about the expiration of the keys you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321267/6845131